# "if $n$ is a composite integer, then $n$ has a prime factor not exceeding ${\sqrt n}$" - proof explanation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

the proof of this theorem was as follows:

since $n$ is composite, then $n=ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers with $1\lt a \le b \lt n$. Suppose now that $a \gt {\sqrt n}$, then

1. $${\sqrt n} \lt a \le b$$

and as a result,

2. $$ab \gt {\sqrt n}{\sqrt n} = n$$

Therfore, $a \le {\sqrt n}$. Also, $a$ must have a prime divisor $a_1$which is also a prime divisor of $n$ thus this divisor is less than  $a_1 \le a \le {\sqrt n}$

What I am having problem with is step 2 I am not sure how this inequality was achieved. I also don't understand the rest of the proof. I would be very grateful if someone could explain it to me.

Comment: In step $1$ you're given $\sqrt{n}<a\le b$, therefore $a>\sqrt{n}$ and $b>\sqrt{n}$, therefore $ab>\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n}=n$. This gives a contradiction (to the assumption that $a>\sqrt{n}$), because you know $n=ab$. Therefore $a\le \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: but the inequality is $ab \gt {\sqrt n}{\sqrt n} $ not $ab \gt b{\sqrt n}$ and i do not think it is given that b = ${\sqrt n}$

Comment: We have the following fact: If $e,f,g,h>0$ and $e>g$ and $f>h$, then $ef>gh$. This fact was used here. (Let $e=a$, $f=b$, $g=h=\sqrt{n}$).

Comment: You may find it helpful to first consider the *additive* analog. If $\,a+b\color{#c00}{=n}\,$ then one of $\,a,b\,$ must be $\le$ their average $\,n/2\,$ (else both would be $> n/2\,$ so their sum would be $\color{#c00}{> n},\,$ contradiction). Yours is a *multiplicative* form of that, using geometric (vs arithmetic) mean

Comment: @user236182: thanks that was helpful !

Comment: @BillDubuque: Thanks as well , that helped me understand the rest of the proof !

Comment: But if n is a negative integer then $\sqrt{n}$ is not defined

Comment: Then how can you say n is a integer.if you say n is a whole number ,then the theorem will be correct.......guys am I right? Or else what is the mistake I'm doing

Comment: @SathasivamK: It did say specifically that $1\lt a \le b \lt n$. So, $n$ is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that if $p$ is positive and $q>r$, then $pq>pr$. Using this twice, we get
$$ab>a\sqrt n = \sqrt n a > \sqrt n \sqrt n = n $$

First we use the fact with $p=a$, $q=b$ and $r=\sqrt n$.

Then we use it again with $p=\sqrt n$, $q=a$ and $r=\sqrt n$.

Comment: can you please explain it more clearly?

Comment: @BasemFouda: Only if you reveal what you find unclear about it.

Comment: sorry, I got it now. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

If $1\lt a \le b \lt n$ and $ \sqrt{n}\lt a$ then

- $ 1 \lt \sqrt{n}$ since both are positive and $1^2 \lt \sqrt{n}^2$
- $ \sqrt{n}\lt a \le b$ and so $ \sqrt{n}\lt b$ by transitivity
- $0 \lt (a-\sqrt{n})\sqrt{n}$ and $0 \lt a(b-\sqrt{n})$ since the real numbers are an ordered field, so  $n=\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n} \lt a \sqrt{n} \lt a b$

Comment: $1 \lt a $ and $\sqrt{n}\lt a$ but how did you get $1 \lt \sqrt{n}$

Comment: I don't able to understand the last step. Can you explain?

Comment: @BasemFouda: $1\lt a \le b \lt n$ so $1 \lt n$ so $1^2 \lt \sqrt{n}^2$ so $ 1 \lt \sqrt{n}$

Comment: @SathasivamK The product of two positive numbers is positive. $0 \lt (a-\sqrt{n})\sqrt{n}$ so $0 \lt a\sqrt{n} -\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n}$ so $\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n} \lt a\sqrt{n}$.  Similarly $0 \lt a(b-\sqrt{n})$ so $0 \lt ab -a\sqrt{n}$ so $a\sqrt{n} \lt ab$.  Combine them for $\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n} \lt a\sqrt{n} \lt ab$