# If $N = ab$ and $b \geq a$ then $N\geq a^2$.

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers

I was reading book "*Higher Algebra* by *Barnard* and *Child*" and got stuck on this theorem.

> *A number N is a prime, if it is not divisible by any prime number and greater than $1$ and less than, or equal to $\sqrt N$.*
>   
>   For, if $N = ab$, where $b \geq a$, then $N \geq a^2$; that is, $a \leq \sqrt N$

As a beginner, How can I proof $N \geq a^2$ ?

Comment: Sorry people, Looks easy but I don't why I can't even solve this. BTW Thanks

Comment: Oddly, this question was asked earlier today.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872738/if-n-is-a-composite-integer-then-n-has-a-prime-factor-not-exceeding-sqr

Answer (score 2):

$N = ab$ and $b \ge a > 0$ so $N =ab \ge a*a = a^2$.

Or if this is more intuitive:

$N = ab$

$N/a = b \ge a$

$N = ba \ge a^2$.

=====

The first time I ever saw this there was not proof. it was presumed as common sense And my common sense was:

$N = \sqrt{N} \sqrt{N}$

If we nudge one factor lower we have to nudge the other factor higher.  I.E

$N = \text{something less than }\sqrt{N}*\text{something bigger than }\sqrt{N}$

So if $N = ab$ then one is less than or equal to the square root, and the other is more than or equal to the square root.

So if $b \ge a$ then $b \ge \sqrt{N}$ and $a \le \sqrt{N}$.

Comment: After reading this, I feel like I should first focus on common sense than maths. *Feeling like, I am most stupid person ever!.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably $a$ and $b$ are supposed to be positive integers here.  In particular, then, $a> 0$, so you can multiply both sides of $b\geq a$ by $a$ to get $ab\geq a^2$, or $N\geq a^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $b\ge a\Rightarrow ab\ge aa=a^2\Rightarrow N\ge a^2$.

Comment: I'm going to nitpick and point out we also need $a > 0$.  But then I'm going to feel bad and upvote your answer to make up for my nitpickiness.